# Extract type of object inside quotation marks

Tags: python, string, list, types, floating-point

I have the following list:

```
l = ['AB', '27.0', '30.5', '28', '31', 'CD', '29']
```

I want to turn each numerical value into `float` and each `string` into `np.nan`.

My attempt so far fails because `float('AB')` obviously can't be computed:

```
result = [float(i) if isinstance(float(i), float) else np.nan for i in l]
```

The desired outcome is:

```
result = [np.nan, 27.0, 30.5, 28.0, 31.0, np.nan, 29.0]
```

What do you suggest that I should do?

Comment: Does it have to be a one-liner…? `list(map(function_that_tries_to_convert_string_to_float_and_catches_exceptions_and_returns_nan_instead, l))`…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Python ideal of ["It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" principle](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html):

> **EAFP**:
> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.

This avoids additional overheads of e.g. a regular expression search, and works with both floats and integers in your input:

```py
def to_float(value: str):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

result = [to_float(value) for value in l]
```

Answer (score 4):

If the numbers are integers like in your example:

```
result = [ float(i) if i.isdigit() else np.nan for i in l ]
```

Comment: Note that this will fail for numbers with decimals like `123.45` and `123,45`. Both of those are not considered digits by `isdigit()`. Considering the author of the question wants to convert to floats and not integers, this could be problematic.

Comment: As I said in the comment "if the numbers are integers". And in the author's example they are. If they can be floats then I would go with `i.replace('.','',1).isdigit()` as suggested in another comment.

Comment: Oh, apologies. I must've read over that part.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.search` instead:

```py
result = [float(i) if re.search(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$', i) else np.nan for i in l]
```

Comment: Regex does not mach `'.1'` :)

Comment: @timgeb The OP's sample data does not make it clear whether or not fractional floats would have a leading zero or not.  If not (and if the OP confirms this) my pattern can be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you just need to find if a string is numeric or not. If its numeric we change to float or else we give it np.nan

so we can work the problem like this:

```
y = []
for x in l:
    if x.isnumeric():
       x = float(x)
       y.append(x)
    else:
        x=np.nan
        y.append(x)
```

EDIT:

We can also tackle the problem is a reverse manner that we check if the string is alphabet or not
So the code can look like this:

```
z = []

for x in l:
    if x.isalpha():
        x = np.nan
        z.append(x)
    else:
        x = float(x)
        z.append(x)
print(z)
```

The result that I got was :

```
[nan, 27.0, 30.5, 28.0, 31.0, nan, 29.0]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `np.nan` is not a function that can be called like `np.nan(x)`. It's just a float. `np.nan("12")` throws `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`.

Comment: please check the edited code

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't work with `l = ['AB', '27.0', '30.5', '28', '31', 'CD', '29']`: `"27.0"` is not considered numeric according to `"27.0".isnumeric()`.

Comment: Then please use the code I posted below with the `isaplha()` function

Comment: That seems to work! I get `[nan, 27.0, 30.5, 28.0, 31.0, nan, 29.0]`, which seems to match what the author wanted.